# responding to someone in a indifferent or perfunctory way

Tags: word-request, verbs

There is a short word meaning responding to someone in a indifferent or perfunctory way. It just escapes me

It is a very short word, maybe three or four letters. It may be a verb. When someone is talking to you, but you are not interested and don't care about what they say, so you want to brush them off or just say one or two words (such as OK, all right) to phone it in.

Can someone help me conjure this word up?

Comment: the only word that comes to mind is [snub](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/snub)

Comment: Can you give a more specific example, like an actual conversation, or how the word is used? There are a lot of words like "meh", "pfft", "huh", "whatevs", "so?" which you can say when you're not bothered, but they're not verbs.

Answer (score 1):

A short or perfunctory answer is a **terse** answer.

Oxford Dictionary:

terse
/tərs/

sparing in the use of words; abrupt.
"a terse statement"

Answer (score 0):

If there were a word you could use in response to someone like 'OK' or 'alright' that had an inherent meaning of disinterest then nobody would use it, otherwise it would confirm they were disinterested.

Really, any word can be said in a disinterested, indifferent manner - like the examples you mentioned of "okay", or "alright". The difference is in your tone. You could say "thanks" or "thank you", even "goodbye" in a way that was dismissive. A very modern example is the response "cool story, bro", which at face value would seem like a compliment, but is now widely understood to be sarcastic.

Comment: but they are not what I am looking for. It is a verb, usually means a very simple response such as OK, Good

Comment: @user135655 ok, your question wasn't clear - I thought you were looking for a word to *describe* that manner, not convey it. I've updated my answer, although you probably won't like it.

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe "dis" to dismiss, to be dismissive, or maybe "ig" to ignore.  I heard "ig" occasionally in the 1980s, along with "igged" as the past tense and "igging" as the gerund form.